# How to change the type of float-point variables in the original program to long double by writing a LLVM pass please?

Tags: llvm

I am writing a LLVM pass to change the type of float-point variables in the original program to long double. A toy test program is:

```
int main(){
    double i = 0.0000000000000001;
    if(i + 1 > 1)
        printf("correct answer");
    else
        printf("wrong answer");
    return 0;
}
```

My pass need to change the type of i to "long double". 
There are five different places between the IR of the original program and the transformed program.

```
<   %i = alloca x86_fp80, align 16
---
>   %i = alloca double, align 8

<   store x86_fp80 0xK3FC9E69594BEC44DE000, x86_fp80* %i, align 16
<   %0 = load x86_fp80, x86_fp80* %i, align 16
<   %add = fadd x86_fp80 %0, 0xK3FFF8000000000000000
<   %cmp = fcmp ogt x86_fp80 %add, 0xK3FFF8000000000000000
---
>   store double 1.000000e-16, double* %i, align 8
>   %0 = load double, double* %i, align 8
>   %add = fadd double %0, 1.000000e+00
>   %cmp = fcmp ogt double %add, 1.000000e+00
```

The outline of my pass to do the above transformation is as follows:

```
virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
    std::string svariable ("i");
    const ValueSymbolTable& symbolTable = F.getValueSymbolTable();
    Value* target = symbolTable.lookup(svariable);
    AllocaInst* old_target = dyn_cast<AllocaInst>(target);
    errs() <<"old_target: " << *target << "\n";
    errs() <<"num of old_target_uses:" << old_target->getNumUses() <<"\n";

    //get the type of long double and construct new AllocaInst
    LLVMContext &context = F.getContext();
    Type* type = Type::getX86_FP80Ty(context);
    unsigned alignment = 16;
    AllocaInst* new_target = new AllocaInst(type, 0, alignment, "new", old_target);
    new_target->takeName(old_target);

    // iterating through instructions using old AllocaInst
    Value::use_iterator it = old_target->use_begin();
    for(; it != old_target->use_end(); it++) {
          Value * temp = it->get();
          errs() <<"temp:" << *temp <<"\n";
          //transform() is under construction
          transform(it, new_target, type, alignment);

    }
    old_target->eraseFromParent();
    return false;
}
```

There should be four instructions related to double i as shown in the IR of the original program:

```
>   store double 1.000000e-16, double* %i, align 8
>   %0 = load double, double* %i, align 8
>   %add = fadd double %0, 1.000000e+00
>   %cmp = fcmp ogt double %add, 1.000000e+00
```

but the output of the pass is not as expected above:

```
old_target: %i = alloca double, align 8
num of old_target_uses:2
temp:  %0 = alloca double, align 8
temp:  %0 = alloca double, align 8
```

So my first question is why the getNumUses() and use_iterator didn't return the correct answer, did I use them in a wrong way in the outline of my pass?

My second question is in my transform() function, I need to enumerate every kind of instruction such as LoadInst, StoreInst, BinaryOperation and reconstruct them with the new type, right?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why did you choose to attack this problem at the LLVM level instead of at the source code level (e.g. using Clang)?

Comment: Many thanks for your comments. Attacking it at the LLVM IR level, I would be able to conveniently support any source language that compile (or will compile) down to LLVM, including C/C++, Fortran, R, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your first question, each [`Use`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/a628d047d14938e7a39666555184edc626972d80/include/llvm/IR/Use.h) object is basically an edge in the data flow graph linking a `Value` (mainly instruction or constant) to one of its `Users` (instruction or constant). Both values can be accessed through `Use::get` and `Use::getUser`, respectively.

```
Value::use_iterator it = old_target->use_begin();
for(; it != old_target->use_end(); it++) {
      Value * temp = it->get();
}
```

Here, when you iterate on uses of `old_target` and assign `temp` to the used value of each use, what is being assigned is actually `old_target` itself. What I believe you're after is `it->getUser`, which will be a *user*, different each time.

Notice that `getNumUses()` is actually correct since in your example `%i` is used twice, first time in `store`, and then in `load`.

> My second question is in my transform() function, I need to enumerate
>   every kind of instruction such as LoadInst, StoreInst, BinaryOperation
>   and reconstruct them with the new type, right?

As for actually replacing types, I think this is roughly what is required here. Note that in general replacing types this way may lead to incorrect results, so you may want to check that no instructions such as `bitcast` or `ptrtoint` operate on these variables first. I suggest you support only `allocas` for sources and a limited subset of instructions operating on those from the start and grow the subset from here.

Then, you would transform each user in a way to accommodate to one of its operands changing type from `double`/`double*` to `x86_fp80`/`x86_fp80*`. If its result type changes, you would need to propagate that also. For that you may find the worklist pattern helpful — that's how many passes in LLVM itself are organized ([example](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/14834723b0672c450fd2cbc632fed78f6c89b4c9/lib/Transforms/Scalar/ConstantProp.cpp#L78-L102)).

The usual means of updating the IR is by `Value::replaceAllUsesWith`. However, in your case the type would most likely change, too, which would cause this function to fail with an error message. So you need to change the IR and types manually, probably using some combination of [User::setOperand](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/492acdd450bcdf9837494d6da029ed064f14fc33/include/llvm/IR/User.h#L138-L144), [Value::mutateType](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/43492b2a7afd5463270a631e5a5dc31f6de513ce/include/llvm/IR/Value.h#L547-L549), and creating new instructions when needed.

For example:

- for `load`, `fadd`, `fcmp` and similar instructions, replace the operand(s) and add the result to the worklist;
- for `store` instruction:

  - if the type of the first operand has changed, abort processing unless the type of the second operand has also changed;
  - if the type of the second operand has changed, but the type of the first one has not changed, convert the first operand to `x86_fp80` (with [fpext](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#fpext-to-instruction));
  - in any case, add the result to the worklist;
- for `call` and `invoke` instructions, cast `x86_fp80` operands to `double` with [fptrunc](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#fptrunc-to-instruction) (or abort, if you want to disallow such downcasts);
- for `bitcast` and `ptrtoint` instructions, abort processing;
- …

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.:) It is very helpful.  It should be getUser() as you said. Many thanks for the helpful advice about transform(), which makes me more clearer about how to write it now.